# How to use JavaScript to validate form before submit in Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I have an HTML page, there are a form and 5 checkboxes in the form.

All the checkboxes should be clicked, then the form can be submitted out.

I want to check if all the checkboxes clicked, this sounds needs JavaScript.

Thus I wrote a JavaScript function in the HTML template file, but it didn't work.

The page went the views.py after been submitted.

How should I do to check the checkboxes?

```
function show_members() {
    var jsonObj = '{"Andy": "10", "Ken": "12", "Tom": 9}'

    var data = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var cbxId = 0
    console.log(data);
    for (var user in data) {
        var age = data[user];
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = user;

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.id = "cbx" + cbxId;
        checkbox.value = age;
        checkbox.name = "ageCbx";
        cell2.appendChild(checkbox);
        cbxId++;
    }
}

function check_fields() {
    var comment= document.getElementsById("comment");
    alert(comment);
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("answerCbx");
    for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.value() == "") {
            if (comment == "") {
                alert("Please input the comment for the unclicked checkboxes.");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


<form
      method="POST"
      action="{% url 'main' %}"
      onsubmit="return check_fields()"
    >
<table id="tbl"></table>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the check_fields() function look like?

Comment: take a look of client-site validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Could you please add your `check_fields` function to your question? It'd really help people trying to answer.

Comment: Hi, I've added the check_fields() function.

Comment: how you checkbox html looks like?